# Unexpected Non-Void Value In Void Function (Swift 3.0)

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous

I am trying to return the annotations array but I'm getting the error below at my return statement.

> Unexpected non-void value in void function

I have done some research and found that I might be trying to return with-in a completion handler but can't seem to find a way around it.

```
func getAnnotations() {

    //The php file connects the Database and Swift
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://test.com/pull.php")! as URL)

    //Receiver's HTTP request method
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        old_data, response, error in

        //Error Checking
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        //Response string built up
        let responseString = NSString(data: old_data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Manipulating JSON data
        do {
            if let new_data = old_data, 
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: new_data) as? [String: Any],
            let buildings = json["buildings"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                var annotations: [ARAnnotation] = []

                for building in buildings {

                    let BUILDING_ID = "BuildingID"
                    let BUILDING_NAME = "BuildingName"
                    let BUILDING_INFO = "BuildingInfo"
                    let BUILDING_LAT = "Latitude"
                    let BUILDING_LNG = "Longitude"

                    let IdString:String = building[BUILDING_ID] as! String
                    let NameString:String = building[BUILDING_NAME] as! String
                    let InfoString:String = building[BUILDING_INFO] as! String

                    let LatString:String = building[BUILDING_LAT] as! String
                    let LatDouble:Double = Double(LatString)!

                    let LngString:String = building[BUILDING_LNG] as! String
                    let LngDouble:Double = Double(LngString)!

                    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LatDouble, LngDouble)

                    let annotation = ARAnnotation()
                    annotation.location = CLLocation(latitude: LatDouble, longitude: LngDouble)
                    annotation.title = "POI: \(NameString)"
                    annotations.append(annotation)

                    return annotations
                    //error
                }  
            }     
        } catch {
            print(error)
        } 
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

My goal of this function is to be able to pull out the variables holding my data (annotations, location, NameString, InfoString...) and use them in another function.

If there is another way rather than a simple return I would love to hear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a Network task, you shouldn't return anything. Because, it takes some time to load data, so you always get an empty array when you call the function. Let use a closure as a completion handler, like this:

```
func getAnnotations(completion: @escaping (_ annotations: [ARAnnotation], _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    //The php file connects the Database and Swift
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://test.com/pull.php")! as URL)

    //Receiver's HTTP request method
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        old_data, response, error in

        //Error Checking
        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        //Response string built up
        let responseString = NSString(data: old_data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Manipulating JSON data
        do {
            if let new_data = old_data,
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: new_data) as? [String: Any],
                let buildings = json["buildings"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                var annotations: [ARAnnotation] = []

                for building in buildings {

                    let BUILDING_ID = "BuildingID"
                    let BUILDING_NAME = "BuildingName"
                    let BUILDING_INFO = "BuildingInfo"
                    let BUILDING_LAT = "Latitude"
                    let BUILDING_LNG = "Longitude"

                    let IdString:String = building[BUILDING_ID] as! String
                    let NameString:String = building[BUILDING_NAME] as! String
                    let InfoString:String = building[BUILDING_INFO] as! String

                    let LatString:String = building[BUILDING_LAT] as! String
                    let LatDouble:Double = Double(LatString)!

                    let LngString:String = building[BUILDING_LNG] as! String
                    let LngDouble:Double = Double(LngString)!

                    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(LatDouble, LngDouble)

                    let annotation = ARAnnotation()
                    annotation.location = CLLocation(latitude: LatDouble, longitude: LngDouble)
                    annotation.title = "POI: \(NameString)"
                    annotations.append(annotation)

                    completion(annotations, nil)
                    //error
                }  
            }     
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion([], error)
        } 
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And use it like this:

```
getAnnotations() { (annotations, error) in

    // TODO: something
    print("annotations: \(annotations), error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Still trying to understand closures. Can you explain how to use the last part of your response? @Danh Huynh

Comment: yes, you should call `getAnnotations` function like that. When the task is completed, it returns an array of `annotations`.